# MUI Autocompleter: Remove input focus on content click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So I'm using MUI's `Autocomplete` on mobile and I have the following issue:
When the dropdown list is open and I have an element inside that list that I would like to interact with (can be a button or anything where I want to click). Once I click on that interaction element, the input is focused and the keyboard pops up.
I don't want this. How can I avoid this?

Here is an example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/small-field-q4y0je?file=/demo.tsx:0-5484

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You want it to be still searchable but not default focused when opened right?

Comment: Not quite! When the result popper is opened, I don't want any clicks within that popper to put focus on the input. Imagine I have some sort of click interaction within that dropdown. This interaction would always trigger the keyboard to pop up on my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I came up with some sort of an acceptable solution.
The problem is that `blurOnSelect` is bound to the autocomplete's options. Since I am extending the autocomplete with custom elements and data, I cannot fully use all the advantages the MUI component brings.
For the input to lose focus I just had to create a reference that saves the input element and once I touch-click on the content, the input is blurred or loses its focus.

Here is an example of this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-jang-r8s67b?file=/demo.tsx

Answer (score 0):

there is a prop in autocomplete called `blurOnSelect`
take a look at it from here
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/

```
 <Autocomplete
        {...defaultProps}
        id="blur-on-select"
        blurOnSelect
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField {...params} label="blurOnSelect" variant="standard" />
        )}
      />
```

Comment: Ah I was hoping for this to work, but unfortunately, it only blurs when you actually select an option. Elements that are not an option do not trigger this it seems.

Comment: If you have an input inside the options .. try e.stopPropagation on the button handler to prevent the autocomplete listener from receiving the event .. i am not sure it is going to work but i would try that if i were you